# How to show metabox in custom php menu page

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, metabox, tinymce, add-menu-page

I've created a custom dashboard for wordpress and I want to show some custom metabox on it. Is there any way to achive this with a filter or function of wordpress? I've tried using the `do_meta_boxes()` function but not worked as expected, and I'm unable to see my registered metabox.